# Lower bound on difference between polynomials at moderate distance

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, st.statistics, polynomials

Fix $r > 0$ and $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n+1}$ be points chosen uniformly from $[-r,r]^{d}$.  For $1 \leq i \leq n+1$, denote by 
$\hat{f}_{k,i}: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow 0$ be the degree-$k$ polynomial obtained by the usual polynomial regression procedure (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) based on the data points 
$( (x_{1},f(x_{1})), \ldots, (x_{i-1}, f(x_{i-1})), (x_{i+1}, f(x_{i+1})), \ldots, (x_{n+1}, f(x_{n+1})))$.

Next, for $\epsilon > 0$, let $\Delta(r, \epsilon) = \inf_{| x | > \epsilon} \sup_{1 \leq i < j \leq n+1} | \hat{f}_{k,i}(x) - \hat{f}_{k,i}(y)|$ be the smallest discrepancy among these estimates, outside of some fixed region of the origin.

Finally, fix some notion of a set $\mathcal{F}$ of "generic" functions. A positive (or negative) answer for any notion of "generic" would help, but to be concrete I say that $\mathcal{F}$ is "generic" if it is a probability-1 set of the functions drawn from a Gaussian process with Matern kernel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process).

**Conjecture**: There exists some generic collection of functions $\mathcal{F}$, some number of points $n = n(d) \in \mathbb{N}$, and constants $\alpha,\beta > 0$ so that for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$,

$\mathbb{P}[\Delta (\epsilon, r) < \epsilon^{\beta}] = O( \epsilon^{\alpha})$,

where the implied constant may depend on the particular function $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

I know that this bound can't be true for all functions (e.g. it isn't true functions that are piecewise polynomials of degree less than or equal to k). I also know that we can't completely drop the randomization of the points (i.e. it isn't true that $\Delta(\epsilon, r) < 1$ for *all* points $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n+1}$) - this can be seen by simply writing out the coefficients of the polynomial regression as a polynomial of the points used to fit it. The vague hope is that, after writing out the coefficients of the polynomial $\hat{f}_{k,i}$ as polynomials in the data, some generic bounds on how often a bunch of polynomials can be close to 0 might be enough to obtain the desired conclusion. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of even trivial bounds in this direction.